# Regular expression does not match when using Regex.Escape

Tags: c#, regex

For the code below, I want:

```
strPattern.IsMatch("@!*()[]{}:?.,^%#$~`:;'_-@!*()[]{}/\\")
```

**to be true**, but almost everything I put in the regex is returning false

Essentially I want:

- strip the html first (no html should be allowed)
- All the characters above, should be a match (these are my allowed characters)
- Everything else should fail

  ```
  string escapedPattern1 = Regex.Escape("@!*()[]{}");
  string escapedPattern2 = Regex.Escape(":?.,^%#$~`:;'_-");
  string escapedPattern3 = Regex.Escape("@!*()[]{}");
  string escapedPattern4 = Regex.Escape(@"/\\");
  string stripped = securityHelper.StripHtml(value);
  string totalPattern = "0-9A-Za-z&" + escapedPattern1 + escapedPattern2 + escapedPattern3 + escapedPattern4;
  Regex strPattern = new Regex("^[" + totalPattern + "]*$");
  ```

Comment: Why two closes? Could someone please advise what is wrong with it?

Comment: (I cheated on the title a bit. Hindsight is 20/20, but also can make a title much more relevant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does *not* handle "-" or "]" and is generally *unsuited* for the contents of a character class. In this case the resulting regular expression will be wrong<sup>1</sup> as they will both have their special meaning.

I would just simplify it and write it manually. I've also removed the redundant characters and fixed other various issues.

```
 Regex p = new Regex(@"^[]0-9A-Za-z&[@!*(){}:?.,^%#$~`;'_/\\-]*$");
 p.IsMatch("@!*()[]{}:?.,^%#$~`:;'_-@!*()[]{}/\\")  // -> true
 p.IsMatch("Hello`World!")                          // -> true
 p.IsMatch("@<")                                    // -> false
```

Notes:

1. To use a `]` in a character class, write it as `[]..]` or (verbatim) `[..\]..]`.
2. To use a `-` in a character class, write it as `[..-]` or (verbatim) `[..\-..]`.

Also, "stripping the HTML" is unrelated.

---

<sup>1</sup> The resulting regular expression in the original post is string is

```
^[0-9A-Za-z&@!\*\(\)\[]\{}:\?\.,\^%\#\$~`:;'_-@!\*\(\)\[]\{}/\\\\]*$
```

and the error is easy to spot once substituting in a dummy placeholder.

```
^[characterclass]\{}:\?\.,\^%\#\$~`:;'_-@!\*\(\)\[]\{}/\\\\]*$
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great, but how do I also put in 0-9A-Za-z& in there? When I try put it in it starts failing

Comment: @Baconbeastnz I've update the post to include those characters.